# Turn on cpu boost state

Tags: opensuse, cpu, laptop, cpu-frequency, boost

Is it possible to set boost cpu frequency on laptop (there is no any cpu settings in bios available)?
If I try set such "boost frequency" it successed, but frequency setting to maximum frequency in non-boost state.
Maybe I doing something incorrect?

```
# cpupower frequency-set -r -f 2900MHz
    Setting cpu: ...
# cpupower frequency-info
    ...
    boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
    Boost States: 4
    Total States: 8
    Pstate-Pb2: ...MHz (boost state)
    Pstate-Pb3: 2600MHz (boost state)
    Pstate-P0:  2400MHz
    Pstate-P1:  ...
```

Additional info:

```
# sudo cpupower --cpu all frequency-info
analyzing CPU 0:
driver: acpi-cpufreq
CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: Not Available
CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: Not Available
maximum transition latency: 4.0 us
hardware limits: 1.40 GHz - 2.40 GHz
available frequency steps:  2.40 GHz, 2.00 GHz, 1.70 GHz, 1.40 GHz
available cpufreq governors: userspace ondemand performance
current policy: frequency should be within 1.40 GHz and 2.40 GHz.
                The governor "userspace" may decide which speed to use
                within this range.
current CPU frequency: 2.40 GHz (asserted by call to hardware)
boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
    Boost States: 4
    Total States: 8
    Pstate-Pb0: 3500MHz (boost state)
    Pstate-Pb1: 3200MHz (boost state)
    Pstate-Pb2: 2900MHz (boost state)
    Pstate-Pb3: 2600MHz (boost state)
    Pstate-P0:  2400MHz
    Pstate-P1:  2000MHz
    Pstate-P2:  1700MHz
    Pstate-P3:  1400MHz

analyzing CPU 1:
driver: acpi-cpufreq
CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: Not Available
CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: Not Available
maximum transition latency: 4.0 us
hardware limits: 1.40 GHz - 2.40 GHz
available frequency steps:  2.40 GHz, 2.00 GHz, 1.70 GHz, 1.40 GHz
available cpufreq governors: userspace ondemand performance
current policy: frequency should be within 1.40 GHz and 2.40 GHz.
                The governor "userspace" may decide which speed to use
                within this range.
current CPU frequency: 2.40 GHz (asserted by call to hardware)
boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
    Boost States: 4
    Total States: 8
    Pstate-Pb0: 3500MHz (boost state)
    Pstate-Pb1: 3200MHz (boost state)
    Pstate-Pb2: 2900MHz (boost state)
    Pstate-Pb3: 2600MHz (boost state)
    Pstate-P0:  2400MHz
    Pstate-P1:  2000MHz
    Pstate-P2:  1700MHz
    Pstate-P3:  1400MHz
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux!  **:-)** What's the full output to `sudo cpupower --cpu all frequency-info`?  Please [edit] your question to provide the additional info.

Comment: @Fabby I've added extra info requested by you

Comment: So no one knows certainly?